# iPhone: TableViewController nibName error with "initWithNibName:bundle:"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, nib

I have a dynamic cell `UITableViewController` and I want to push a specific View Controller when someone taps a cell. So I'm trying to use the pre-made method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

But when I go into the simulator and tap a cell, this is what I get:

```
"NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle [...] with name 'AffichageVotesQuestionDuMomentViewController'.
```

Within the method, I have this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.

     AffichageVotesQuestionDuMomentViewController *detailViewController = [[AffichageVotesQuestionDuMomentViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AffichageVotesQuestionDuMomentViewController" bundle:nil];

    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

}
```

`AffichageVotesQuestionDuMomentViewController` is a custom view controller I created myself. I also tried creating another random one and I get the same type of error. If I set the `initWithNibName:` to `nil`, it segues to a view controller that has the navigation bar on top, but that's completely black.

Now, I'm a beginning iPhone programmer and have a very poor understanding of nibs, nib names and such. Any help is appreciated. Also, I didn't do any segue in the storyboard or anything, since it seems I'm programmatically creating the view controller and pushing that way. If there's a good way to do it with segue though, I'm okay with that too (but I need to know the row of the tapped cell).

Thank you!

Comment: you are not calling the right xib name or, the xib is not in your bundle

Comment: I think I'm doing everything I'm supposed to. I've got this view controller file, .h and .m, it has the right name, it has everything it needs inside... So how come it's not working? Do I need to do something with the Storyboard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're using IB storyboards you should do something lik this i think:

```
UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"mystoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController* vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AffichageVotesQuestionDuMomentViewController"];
```

... instead of using the "initWithNibName"-initializer which is used for the classical xib-based approach.

Comment: This works :) Thanks a lot. Can you explain why I need to do this though? It's a bit confusing to me (I have no idea what a xib is).

Comment: Hi Konrad! It's just the way things work with storyboards now i think! :) just look up the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIStoryboard/instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:) for it.